# ui:repeat value expressions evaluated during render response regardless of rendered attribute of a parent component

Tags: jsf-2, nullpointerexception, facelets, el, uirepeat

We are migrating an old Seam webapp (Seam 2.2, JSF 1.2, JBoss 5.1) to JBoss 7.1 (Seam 2.3, JSF 2.0) and facing this srange problem:

All the EL expressions as value of `<ui:repeat>` within conditionally rendered `<s:fragement>` tags are evaluated to `null` which causes NPE during render response phase. The strange thing is, why did Facelets or JSF try to evaluate these EL expressions although the conditions (the `rendered` attribute of `<s:fragment>`) for them to be rendered didn't apply?

Comment: Ignoring the technical problem for now (I don't recognize this for now, perhaps Seam related), this indicates a design problem: you're doing business job in a getter method. Why?

Comment: Im not doing any logic in those expressions, they are just a chain of getter calls. These same expressions, when places elsewhere (as value of h:outputText beside the ui:repeat) did not make any trouble! So, the trouble maker seems to be the ui:repeat tag within the conditional rendered <s:fragment> tags

Comment: EL is normally null-safe. The NPE can only originate in business logic. I'm curious to the stacktrace, just to check if you interpreted the problem right.

Comment: I have a similar issue where I wrap tags in s:fragment because the backing object is of various types and it is only possible to evaluate certain tags if the backing object is of a certain type. This code now fails because the tags are being evaluated when they should not be.